# How do I capture the "Enter" key in a windows form?

Tags: c#, textbox, keypress, enter

I am trying to get the text of a textbox and save it to a variable when the user presses the enter key (when the textbox has info and is focused) since this is already inside a method i haven't been able to put another method inside like txtbox1_keypress (or i've been doing it wrong)  so I need to be just code lines that i can insert in this method

```
private void df1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtres.Focus();
    //timer
    timeLeft = 50;
    timer1.Start();
    //mult
    do
    {
        ban = 0;
        m1 = r.Next(1, 4);
        txtm1.Text = m1.ToString();
        m2 = r.Next(2, 6);
        txtm2.Text = m2.ToString();
        res = m1 * m2;
        //here is where i want to read txtm2 and continue with the rest
        if(txtres.Text == res.ToString())
        {
            pun++;
        }
        ban++;
    } while (timeLeft > 0 || ban != 10);
    if(pun == 10 && level == 0)
    {
        level++;
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@".\level.lvl", level.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: what?  code sample, with explanation.

Comment: so you are running a timer and wants to get user input from a text box?

Comment: wll timer doesn't matter, i just want to read the content of the txtres with an enter key

Comment: You're trying to capture user input inside a loop that runs on the UI thread; this isn't going to work since your UI will be unresponsive to keyboard inputs.

Comment: You will need to add another method, called an `EventHandler`, which will respond to the `KeyUp`, or `KeyDown`, or `KeyPress` event of your `TextBox`.

Comment: can i add a pause then? or something to stop it

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned you want to run it inside `KeyPress` event, here is the example:

```
 private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
      if (e.KeyChar == (int) Keys.Enter)
      {
        //do the logic
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a button as the accept button of the form, this will trigger whenever enter is pressed.
Also, your loop (do -- while) should be done within the timer1_tick method, and take out the loop, the timer will execute the code within every interval it ticks until the timer reaches your maximum of 50.
As was mentioned, the loop will kill your GUI and it wont allow input.